# difference between starting with a function or not, i need some understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can someone tell me the difference between using

```
$(function() {
    $("#tab_1").click(function() {
        $('.loadContent').load('page1.html');
    });
});
```

and

```
$("#tab_2").click(function() {
    $('.loadContent').load('page2.html');
});
```

they both achieve the same result and i don't know which is the best practices. Thanks

Comment: I think the first one is used most commonly with document.ready(function etc... so you run a function when the page is finished loading, but I'm not fully sure, not an expert here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$(function () {})` is called DOM Ready. When you want to access an element, for example `#tab_2`, you should wait for browser to load DOM successfully.

In your second example, the code **won't work** if you put it in the `head` section (before your element which you want to access it).

---

**This example won't work:**
*because DOM isn't ready yet, the script is executed before `#elem`*

```css
#elem {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#elem').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
  });
</script>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

---

**This example will work:** *because DOM is ready, the script is executed after `#elem`*

```css
#elem {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem"></div>
<script>
  $('#elem').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
  });
</script>
```

---

**SO**, you can:

1. Put your `script` before `</body>` to ensure DOM is ready for accessing elements.
2. Put your `script` in `<head>` section and wrap all your code within `$(function () { });`.

In the second way, our first example will be:

```css
#elem {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#elem').on('click', function () {
      $(this).css('background', 'green');
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="elem"></div>
```

That **works correctly**, as the script inside `$(function () {})`, will be executed after DOM ready,
so the `#elem` is defined.

Comment: consider doing the first example again with the function(){} wrapper for another "will work", and a direct answer to the OP.

Comment: wait.. what if i have declared $(document).ready(function(){}); in my js file? Since it is already waiting for everything to be loaded. I can skip the $(function () {}); and go straight to $("#tab_1").click(function() {
        $('.loadContent').load('page1.html');
    }); right? @ROX

Comment: @Devon No, there is no different between internal or external script, if you put it in the `head` section, you need to wait for DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use function loadpage1() { so you can call the function on other events too though.  That would be why you'd use a function there.  Generally I'd put that inside a $(document).read(function() { function if you're putting it in the header, otherwise you should be fine.